# Getting the $x$-intercept of $f(x) = -16x^2 + 80x + 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x) = -16x^2 + 80x + 5$$

I need to find the bigger value of $x$ that makes $f(x) = 0$.

Naturally, I thought to do:
$$0=-16x^2+80x+5$$
and I applied the quadratic formula

$$0=\frac{-80\pm\sqrt{6080}}{-32}$$
but the answer doesn't seem like it would be correct.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You made a minus sign error. A few thousand  more and you can apply for membership in my club. By the way, when solving the quadratic equation, I would automatically write it as $16x^2-80x-5=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the discriminant $\Delta$: $$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = 80^2-4(-16)5=6400+320=6720$$

$$\sqrt{6720} = 8\sqrt{105}$$

And so our "zeros" are $$x_1, x_2 = \frac{-80\pm\sqrt{6720}}{-32}= \frac{-80 \pm 8\sqrt{105}}{-32} = \frac 52 \pm\frac{\sqrt {105}}{4}$$

Comment: Could use another TU +1

Answer (score 2):

The discriminant is $80^2-4(-16)5=6400+320=6720$ and **not** $6400-320=6080$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please remember that the $x$-intercept is where the graph $y = \operatorname{f}(x)$ meets the $x$-axis. If you're not plotting a graph then it doesn't make sense to talk about $x$- and $y$-intercepts.

You're looking for the *solutions* to the equation $\operatorname{f}(x)=0$.

If $\operatorname{f}(x)=-16x^2+80x+5$ then you need to solve $-16x^2+80x+5=0$. The quadratic formula can be used where $a=-16$, $b=80$ and $c=5$. We have:
$$\begin{array}
.x &=& \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\ \\
&=& \frac{-80 \pm \sqrt{(80)^2-4(-16)(5)}}{2(-16)} \\ \\
&=& \frac{-80\pm\sqrt{6720}}{-32} \\ \\
&=& \tfrac{5}{2} \pm \tfrac{1}{4}\sqrt{105}
\end{array}$$